# My MapViewer stopped loading the layers unexpectedly and giving error 500

Tags: geoserver, wms, layers

I have developed a  MapViewer with around 140 different layers with renewable energy information from the West African region which are all public and free for download. www.ecowrex.org/mapView The layers (vector files and raster files) are stored in GeoServer here:
www.ecowrex.org:8080/geoserver/web/?wicket:bookmarkablePage=:org.geoserver.web.demo.MapPreviewPage

Some days ago out of nowhere all of the layers have failed to load when selected. When I inspect the console for errors in the browser I see the error "500 (Internal Server Error)" each time it attempts to fetch the layer.

[image: Erros in the Console]
For some reason in the console when it tries to access the url of the layer, the port :8080 is not there after the host. But if I copy and paste the url to my browser and add the port myself I see the layer (ex: http://www.ecowrex.org:8080/geoserver/ecreee/wms?TILED=false&LAYERS=ecreee%3Aecowas_country_admin&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&SRS=EPSG%3A900913&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=-7239270.7789323,-100001.97671781,6125590.7408137,3451568.1050302&WIDTH=1366&HEIGHT=363).

Can that be an indication of what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that your website is running on port 80 but geoserver is running at port 8080.

When your request is generated by clicking on the layer options in layer selector, it goes on port no 80 instead of 8080, which is wrong.

Please amend your code to for all geoserver WMS request to go to port 8080. Your problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I will add one more point to explanation of GeoSpatialEarth.in. In most cases web servers only allow traffic over port 80 and 8080 is blocked by firewalls. In such a case reverse proxy may be used to redirect traffic coming in specified format to port 80 to port 8080. I mean if only traffic that should go to 8080 is in specific format(i.e. contains *wms*) request like  http://www.ecowrex.org/geoserver/ecreee/wms? can be automatically redirected to  http://www.ecowrex.org:8080/geoserver/ecreee/wms?. You may check url rewrite and reverse proxies. 
Using only port 80 for network traffic is not only useful when your network blocks traffic on other ports but also if clients network does not allow traffic on any port except 80.